# is that a good idea to have a CustomIdGenerator that uses an ID entity in doctrine?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I have different objects and have a need that each object has a unique identifier.
I already anaylze the uuid question but for a performance issue, I would like to have only int/bigint identifier.

So I have put in place for my entities a CustomIdGenerator that use the IdEntity to create an id and then use the EntityManager to persist and flush it.
Is that a good idea ?

I have faced a problem that when the main entity try to flush and there was a problem the IdEntity increase the counter of the Id table without creating the Id itself. 
So i have hole in my table and I was wondering if that was a good idea to have a kind of inception in flushing entity that flush another entity

Answer (score 0):

the self-generated ones are a good idea in most of the occasions, mainly because they are managed by the system without you having to take care of it. Doctrine in particular does very well.

I personally just stop using it sometimes if I have to show that identifier to users and then it must be something more complex than a number.

You should not worry if a number jumps in the account, the important thing is that each tuple is uniquely identified. Think about it, if a user, properly and consciously, deletes a record, will not the consecutive one also skip?